# Lazy high charts formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

How do i get rid of the y-axis range at the bottom of the chart?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKJeD.png

Ive tried changing minRange and title but it doesn't do anything

```
  f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "column"
  f.options[:title][:text] = "Book Catalog"
  f.options[:yAxis][:minRange] = 0;
  f.options[:yAxis][:title] = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like this:

```
 f.options[:xAxis] = {
    :title => { :text => nil },
    :labels => { :enabled => false }
 }
```

As far as I don't know RoR, I've created a JS demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Srv8Z/